# How to solve 2nd order inhomogeneous ODE with Green function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems, greens-function

I'm studying Green function and get confused by some basic problems. For a 2nd order inhomogeneous ODE, we can solve it by constructing Green function.

$$y''+py'+qy=f(x)$$
where $p$ and $q$ are constants.

Quenstion:

1. How to construct Green function?
2. why does Green function $G(t,t')$ have different solution for $t<t'$ and $t>t'$?
3. How do boundary condition and initial value play the role for the construction of Green function?

Comment: Do you know about variation of parameters?

Comment: To make the question easier, I set $p$ and $q$ constants first.

Comment: I suggest learning about variation of parameters first. Then you will have the context for the rest of the problem.

Comment: But what is the difference between "Wronskian (variation parameter)" and "green function"? Are they as same?